# Extracting a JSON file

Tags: json

I need some advice please.  I have a json file  - sorry for the amount of text.  I need to extract something like this

"name":"Buzz"
"abv":4.5,

To be something like this -

Buzz,14.5

Becca,9.0

apple,4.5

grape,9.0

I have tried using "`grep -Po '"name":.*?[^\\]",' file.json | sed "s/\"//g" | sed "s/name:"//g`
But I was wondering if there was a better to use "jq" command to get both name and abv.  In addition to check if abv is greater than a certain value e.g. >= 4.5 and sort both column 2 (abv).

apple,4.5

Becca,9.0

grape,9.0

Buzz,14.5

Yes I know I need to run a loop and python could better, but I am more comfortable with bash.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

## JSON file

`[{"id":1,"name`

Comment: Don't use regular expressions.  Use a JSON parser.  From the command-line, you can use https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: I have alerady installed jq, but i need some advice on the command.  Not familar in the commands.

Comment: There are a *lot* of tutorials and very good documentation at that site.

Comment: Yes, i have been exploring...